# how to print block of lines not matching a block

Tags: linux

I have a log file with call stacks. i dont want to print a call stack but want all other call stacks to be printed.
the call stacks are seperated by blank line

how can i do this using grep/sed/awk?
Example file:

```
func1
func2
func3

func4
func5

func6
func7
func8
func9
```

I want all line except the callstack block containing func4 , func5.

Desired output:

```
func1
func2
func3

func6
func7
func8
func9
```

I know names of last function in call stack that i want to ignore. for ex i know func5
Thanks for help

Comment: Don't want `A` but want all other `A` printed? Huh?

Comment: Provide an example input file and an example output you want.

Comment: How do you distinguish between call stacks you want to print versus those you don't want to print?

Comment: i know names of function that i dont care, say func5 in above example

Answer (score 1):

With awk you could try something of the form

```
awk '/func4/ {x=1} !x{print} x&&/^\s*$/{x=0}' < logfile
```

The trick here is to use a variable, x, in order to decide whether we should print the current line.

Should we know only the last function of the block we don't want to print (say func5), we can reverse the input before processing and after processing:

```
tac logfile | awk '/func5/ {x=1} !x{print} x&&/^\s*$/{x=0}' | tac
```

Comment: i know only last function of a call stack that i want to ignore. In above example, i know only func5 (not func4)

Comment: thanks, quick test shows it works, will test more, thanks for quick answer

Comment: Of course you could use it with multiple functions... just put something like /func5|func66/ in the first regex.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of ambiguety in your question, but if i understood you right, it sounds like you want an inverse grep, `grep -v`. Running consecutive pipes, one for each unwanted function should do the trick:

```
cat logfile.log | grep -v func4 | grep -v func5
```

Comment: this work only if call stack has 2 functions. gets very complicated when the it has more.

Comment: hence the ambiguety i refer to in my answer. Nowhere in your question does it say that the amount of functions is arbitrary.